# How to cause a chrome extension to close only by clicking on the icon or a button

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am developing a chrome extension, in which I have used `iframe`, which I want to keep open even if we do some activity on the active web page itself or open a new tab or a new window. The extension should get closed only on clicking on the extension icon again or by clicking a close button, present on the extension itself. I am hinting on something like `join pouch` extension.

Other questions pertaining to this topic only caters to opening a window through extension which remains open or keeping the extension popup open just for debugging purposes, by inspecting the popup.

I know there is a way to do this, since I have seen some extensions as such, but am unable to find.

Comment: There is no other way to keep the popup window open in Chrome. The additional workaround not mentioned in your question is to insert a DOM element/iframe with the UI into the active tab (using the content script, of course).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can embed that *iframe* into the DOM structure of every single page you open. Unfortunately, Google doesn't provide any solution besides a default popup that disappears when the first click outside of it happens. The flipside is, you'll need to run one instance of your content script per page, which might mean there will be hundreds of them running (at least for me as I'm a compulsive new-tab-opener).

This is one of the ways, how you can approach this.

**Step 1.** As I've already  said, the default action on icon click is opening a popup. You can disable that behaviour by including the following entry in your `manifest.json`:

```
"browser_action": {},
```

**Step 2.** The next thing would be creating a content script that runs on every page. In your manifest, it would look like this:

```
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "run_at": "document_end",
    "matches": ["*://*/*"],
    "js": ["path/to/your/content/script.js"]
  }
],
```

**Step 3.**
Your content script should embed that *iframe* you mentioned into the currently open page (when the DOM fully loaded).

```
window.addEventListener('load', function load(event) {
  var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
  /* some settings, these are mine */
  iframe.style.width = "250px";
  iframe.style.background = "#eee";
  iframe.style.height = "100%";
  iframe.style.position = "fixed";
  iframe.style.top = "0px";
  iframe.style.right = "0px";
  iframe.style.zIndex = "1000000000000000";
  iframe.frameBorder = "none";
  /* end of settings */
  iframe.src = 
  chrome.runtime.getURL("path/to/contents/of/your/iframe.html");
  document.body.appendChild(iframe);
});
```

**Step 4.**
You must make sure, people can access `iframe.html`. Add this line to your manifest file:

```
"web_accessible_resources": ["path/to/contents/of/your/iframe.html"],
```

(or just add that file to the list if it was already there.

**Step 5.**
Create a function in your content script that knows how to hide your iframe. Something like that:

```
function toggle_iframe() {
  if (iframe.style.width == "0px"){
    iframe.style.width="250px";
  } else {
    iframe.style.width="0px";
  }
}
```

Now, the only thing left is to know when to call it.

**Step 6.**
Unfortunately, background script is the only place that can get information about extension icon being clicked. Add this snippet to your background script:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(){
  chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs){
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, { action: "must_toggle_iframe" });
  })
});
```

It sends a message, when the icon has been clicked.

**Step 7.**
The last part is to allow your content script to receive that message. Your content script needs a listener.

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(msg, sender) {
  if (msg.action == "must_toggle_iframe"){
    toggle_iframe();
  }
}
```

Of course, the solution is not ideal, but you could refine it. For example by remembering in the `chrome.storage.local/chrome.storage.sync` whether the iframe has been hidden.

Comment: I did the relevant changes as guided, and set the _iframe_ settings acoordingly too, but now the _iframe_ isn't appearing even on clicking the extension icon for the first time

Comment: I haven't seen any of your code, so it's hard for me to guess. Have your got any errors in the console? Maybe use some console.logs() to figure out which part failed? Does the content script even run on that page? Is there an iframe that has been injected to DOM? Has the event in background fired? Has content script received it? Has it called *toogle_iframe*?

Comment: After I added `"web_accessible_resources": [ "frame.html"  ],` to the _manifest.json_ , the _iframe_ is being loaded, but _iframe_ doesn't seem to run another js file in my extension, _popup.js_ properly . Also, the _iframe_ opens automatically, without clicking on the icon and is embedded  permanently and doesn't close whatsoever, until I remove the extension itself. If I could add a button to close the iframe.

Comment: My best guess is: 1. You create that iframe before the page is fully loaded, so there's no `<body>` yet. 2. You are probably missing `"web_accessible_resources": ["path/to/contents/of/your/iframe.html"],` entry in the manifest. I updated the instructions accordingly.

Comment: `popup.js` must be specified as `web_accessible_resource` as well. I just have `"web_accessible_resources": ["static/*"],` and put all the images, .html and .js related to iframe in that directory.

Comment: If you want it to be collapsed by default, just set `iframe.style.width = "0px"` when creating that iframe. Make sure `toggle_iframe` is called upon icon click. Something's wrong there if it doesn't hide/show up.